# Makefile with different source types doesn't notice make.depend

Tags: makefile

I want my Makefile to accept different source file types. It does, but it does not recompile when I alter an include file. Here's the Makefile:

```
C_SOURCES       := $(wildcard *.c)          
CPP_SOURCES     := $(wildcard *.cpp)
CC_SOURCES      := $(wildcard *.cc)
ALL_SOURCES     := $(notdir $(C_SOURCES) $(CPP_SOURCES) $(CC_SOURCES))

C_OBJECTS       := ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}
CPP_OBJECTS     := ${CPP_SOURCES:.cpp=.o}
CC_OBJECTS      := ${CC_SOURCES:.cc=.o}
ALL_OBJECTS     := $(notdir $(C_OBJECTS) $(CPP_OBJECTS) $(CC_OBJECTS))

#############################################################

all: a.out

a.out: $(ALL_OBJECTS)
    g++ -o $@ -g $^

%.o:    %.cpp
        g++ -c $@ -g $^

%.o:    %.cc
        g++ -c $@ -g $^

%.o:    %.c
        g++ -c $@ -g $^

clean:
    rm -f a.out
    rm -f *.o

make.depend: $(ALL_SOURCES) 
        g++ -MM $^ > $@ 

-include make.depend
```

The lines starting with *.o: are a recent addition -- I wondered if it might help. No effect.

make.depend is doing its job: I checked it out, and its dependencies are correct. (For my MCVE I have one source file main.cpp which includes date.h.)

```
main.o: main.cpp date.h
```

The output of `$(info $(ALL_OBJECTS))` is `main.o`.

So: how can I get it to recognize changes to includes?

Comment: The compile rules are quite broken. They try to compile the non-existing object files as C files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** Just use the comprehensively enginerred automatic dependency file generation [@MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist) describes at http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/. This works with both GCC and clang (due to clang's explicit goal to be commandline compatible to GCC).

**For completeness' sake, my original answer:**

The generated dependency rules must depend on the sources determined by the dependeny rule generating rule. This requires the `-MT` parameter to `gcc`.

I have included this as an example in a slightly cleaned up version of your `GNUmakefile`:

```
#############################################################

ALL_CFLAGS   = -g
ALL_CXXFLAGS = -g

#############################################################

.PHONY: all
all: all-local

#############################################################

bin_PROGRAMS += test-cxx

test_cxx_OBJECTS += main.o
test_cxx_OBJECTS += main-c.o

test-cxx: $(test_cxx_OBJECTS)
    $(LINK.cc) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

ALL_OBJECTS += $(test_cxx_OBJECTS)

#############################################################

%.o: %.cpp
    $(COMPILE.cpp) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.cc
    $(COMPILE.cc)  $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE.c)   $(ALL_CFLAGS)   -o $@ -c $<

#############################################################

%.dep: %.cpp
    $(COMPILE.cpp) -MM -MT "$*.o $@ " $< > $@.tmp
    mv -f $@.tmp $@

%.dep: %.cc
    $(COMPILE.cc)  -MM -MT "$*.o $@ " $< > $@.tmp
    mv -f $@.tmp $@

%.dep: %.c
    $(COMPILE.c)   -MM -MT "$*.o $@ " $< > $@.tmp
    mv -f $@.tmp $@

ALL_DEPS = $(ALL_OBJECTS:.o=.dep)
-include $(ALL_DEPS)

#############################################################

.PHONY: all-local
all-local: $(bin_PROGRAMS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(bin_PROGRAMS)
    rm -f *.dep
    rm -f *.o

#############################################################
```

The `*.dep` generating rules will recursively examine all included source files, and list them all in the generated `*.dep` file.

Using a separate `*.dep` file for each object file means that if you change only one source file, only the `*.dep` files needing regeneration will actually be regenerated.

The `*.dep` generating rule creates a `*.dep.tmp` file first, and only moves that to `*.dep` if generating the `*.dep.tmp` file has been successful. So if for some reason generating the `*.dep.tmp` file fails (e.g. you might be including a non-existing header file), you will not have a newly generated (and thus considered up to date) empty `*.dep` file being included by `make`.

Comment: Love it! Can you tell me why you generated the dependencies into .tmp files, then moved them? I simplified that and it worked, but...

Comment: I didn't find the spaces before the colons had the effect: I edited one of my .dep files, touched one of the dependencies, did a make, and it did recreate the .dep file, replacing the rule. Is there a reason I might want to add to, rather than replace, the rule? Tx.

Comment: Spaces around colons are irrelevant: make works the same way with or without them.  Although this method works, there are actually a number of downsides to this method of generating dependencies.  In a way your original method of creating a single deps file has _fewer_ gotchas than this method.  If you want an even more bullet-proof--and efficient!--method you can consider http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: It would be nice to put this in the answer (feel free). make started rebuilding the .dep's every time, even if I said make clean. Solution: `ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean) <newline>
-include $(ALL_DEPS) <newline>
endif  `

Comment: @TopologicalSort Better just move to MadScientist's bullet-proof method. Had I known about that method, I would have suggested that method from the start, and been using it for decades.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful, when asking questions, to show an example of running the commands and what is printed.  Given the makefile you provide I'd be surprised of make actually ran any commands at all, other than generating the depend file.

That's because this:

```
C_OBJECTS       := ${C_SOURCES:     .c  =.o}
```

is invalid syntax.  Or more precisely, it doesn't do what you want to do.  It replaces the literal string `_____.c__` (where the `_` are whitespace... SO won't let me just use spaces) at the end of each word in `C_SOURCES` with `.o`.  Of course you don't have any of those, so basically your `ALL_OBJECTS` variable contains just your source files (since no changes are made by the substitution).

You can use:

```
$(info $(ALL_OBJECTS))
```

to see what happens here.

This needs to be written:

```
C_OBJECTS       := ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}
CPP_OBJECTS     := ${CPP_SOURCES:.cpp=.o}
CC_OBJECTS      := ${CC_SOURCES:.cc=.o}
```

Whitespace in makefiles is very tricky.  You definitely have to be careful where you put it and you can't add it anywhere you like.

Also I have no idea why you're using `notdir` since all your files are in the current directory.

And technically it's incorrect to compile `.c` files with the `g++` compiler front-end.

*ETA* also your pattern rules are incorrect: you're missing the `-o` option to the compiler; they should all be the equivalent of:

```
%.o:    %.c
        g++ -c -o $@ -g $^
```

Better is to use the standard make variables, then you can customize the behavior without rewriting all the rules:

```
CFLAGS = -g

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: The output is `g++ -o a.out -g main.cpp` if I clean it, and `make: nothing to be done for 'all'` if I mess up the include file and test make for noticing. I will remove the whitespace as soon as I can and see if that makes it notice the dependencies. Tx.

Comment: The output of `$(info $(ALL_OBJECTS))` is `main.o`.

Comment: The link line in your first comment uses `main.cpp`, not `main.o`, so my suggestion as to the cause was correct: `ALL_OBJECTS` must have been set to `main.cpp`, not `main.o`, to get this output.  Now that you've fixed the makefile to set `ALL_OBJECTS` correctly (as per your second commentd and update of the question), what happens?

Comment: No change. I do note there isn't a command that creates any .o files. I'd be happy to have them, but the commands that I set to create .o's are not having any effect.

Comment: There must be something else happening here that you're not showing us.  It's not possible for you to get a link line that contains the `-g` and also the `main.cpp`, if your `ALL_OBJECTS` variable contains only `main.o` and not `main.cpp`.  I see you accepted another answer with a completely rewritten solution.  If you want to figure out why your original attempt was not working, it would be better if you edited your question to contain the exact makefile AND show the command you typed and the output you got: writing formatted text in comments is too hard to read and understand.

Comment: I showed everything I've seen, so surely the problem is reproducible. Anyway, yes, I was able to adapt the provided solution to work with my own Makefile, so that's good. It's not ideal that make clean is rebuilding the dependencies, though.

Comment: Nope.  I pasted your makefile locally and ran `touch main.c` and what you mention above is NOT what I saw.  I got this: `g++ -MM main.c > make.depend` ... `g++ -c main.o -g main.c` ... `g++: error: main.o: No such file or directory`.  The latter error is because your pattern rules are written incorrectly: they are missing the `-o` option.  I definitely did not see the command `g++ -o a.out -g main.cpp`, as I expected I wouldn't.  Regarding the "not ideal" solution, look at the blog post I referenced in a comment on that solution for a better one.